El significado de "propuesta" en "Siloé es una de las propuestas más originales de la escena musical española."
Quisiera confirmar si "propuesta" en "Siloé es una de las propuestas más originales de la escena musical española" significa "idea" (una de las definiciones de la RAE. Es que no creo que signifique "consulta" en este caso. Sin embargo, "idea" tampoco suena bien en mi humilde opinión. ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

En el mundo del arte, es muy común hablar de "propuesta" para referirse a un modo de presentar una expresión artística, sea una obra de teatro, una exhibición de danza, una exposición de pintura o escultura, etc.
Creo que la primera acepción que da la RAE se ajusta bastante bien a este significado:

Proposición o idea que se manifiesta y ofrece a alguien para un fin.

Los productores de Siloé proponen u ofrecen al público una puesta en escena que se destaca por ser diferente de las demás.
